# Best practice for archiving old data?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, backup

We are migrating 3 slightly different SQL databases into one (SQL Server 2008R2). We want to keep old databases "alive" for some period of time but once we've gone live we don’t want staff accidentally going into old database, so taking the database offline for awhile then drop it would be the solution? taking backups for it and test it in another serve prior to do this of course.

I’m not sure what best practice is for making archives, but suspect that making SQL server backups and placing on tape may be a solution.  Do you know if SQL Server backups are compressed and can be saved to tape?  There may be better solutions than tape these days, but I think tape is still the standard.

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Thanks Aaron, actually when asked our IT to see how they are backing up our server that have copies of our nightly full SQL Server backups sent to, and the reply was that their backup is written nightly to tape and its saved for a 2 weeks rotation, just in case if we experience any issues, then we just provide them the exact path to restore and the date... 
The merged database file size is almost 1.75GB, so I will just make several full backups for the older 3 databases that are coming from, and not sure if I should compress these backups before archiving but thanks for any input.

Answer (score 4):

> We want to keep old databases "alive" for some period of time but once we've gone live we don’t want staff accidentally going into old database, so taking the database offline for awhile then drop it would be the solution?

Instead of making database OFFLINE, make the database "READ ONLY" using :

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name SET READ_ONLY
```

And monitor what apps/ users are still connecting using server side trace.

> Do you know if SQL Server backups are compressed and can be saved to tape?

Yes, backup compression is available in sql server 2008 R2 standard edition and up.

Enable backup compression :

```
EXEC sp_configure 'backup compression default', 1 ;
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE ;
```

When taking backups, use `BACKUP DATABASE ... with COMPRESSION`.

You can save the backups to tape. Thats what we do in our company as well for data retention (We have to retain data for 10+ years). Alternatively, you can use [Windows Azure Blob Storage Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj919148.aspx).

Make sure that the archive bit is set (attribute 'A' on the backup file).

Comment: With READ_ONLY you allow people to query (potentially) stale data.  There's a risk there.

Comment: @ZabadakGalorex thats true, but the OP wants it `We want to keep old databases "alive" for some period of time but once we've gone live we don’t want staff accidentally going into old database`. So if he puts the database OFFLINE, there is no way of keeping old databases "Alive".

Comment: True, I guess I was reading it as "we don't want anyone reading the old copy at all but we want it available if needed".  Otherwise yeah READ_ONLY while both are 'alive' then OFFLINE when the switchover is complete.  Some tweaking of database permissions on the old copy could mitigate some of the risk too.

Comment: Yes as my understanding is when they merged all data, that means even old data have been migrated over to the new database, keeping these old databases alive just in case if something didn't migrate correctly so only admin users can access these databases back until the switch over date. What did you mean by DB permissions... could mitigate some of the risk too? Do you mean users permissions to the database might change?

Comment: Kin, from the T-SQL code that the job step is showing, the full backup is not compressed. I thought compression is not good for data!, so you are recommending it? 

See code below:
EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_create_subdir N'E:\AP3 Doc Management DB Backup\WDDocumentManagement'
GO
BACKUP DATABASE [WDDocumentManagement] TO  DISK = N'E:\AP3 Doc Management DB Backup\WDDocumentManagement\WDDocumentManagement_backup_2015_02_09_143817_0183218.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'WDDocumentManagement_backup_2015_02_09_143817_0026971', SKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
declare @backupSetId as int.....